# How to get particular fields in Preload while using Gorm

Tags: go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I have two models which have many to many relations.

```
type User struct {
    ID        uint      `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Surname   string    `json:"surname"`
    Email     string    `json:"email"`
    Password  string    `json:"password"`
    RoleID    uint      `json:"role_id"`
    Classes   []*Class  `gorm:"many2many:user_classes;" json:"classes"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

```
type Class struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    Name      string     `json:"name"`
    Homeworks []Homework `gorm:"foreignKey:ClassID" json:"homeworks"`
    Materials []Material `gorm:"foreignKey:ClassID" json:"materials"`
    Users     []*User    `gorm:"many2many:classes;" json:"users"`
    CreatedAt time.Time  `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time  `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

I want to get users with their classes but with only class id and class name. I did a lot of research and found this solution. However, it didn't work for me. I don't know why. Everything seems fine but didn't work.

My repository function's body is like that

```
var users []models.User
    err := repo.db.Preload("Classes", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select("ID", "Name")
    }).Find(&users).Error

    return users, err
```

I am expecting results like that

```
{
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Furkan",
            "surname": "Topaloğlu",
            "email": "furkantopalogluu@gmail.com",
            "password": "fuki123",
            "role_id": 2,
            "classes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "IELTS Group 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Speaking Club Grup 4"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2022-09-20T02:54:07.185756+03:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-09-20T02:54:07.185756+03:00"
}
```

However, I'm getting this :

```
{
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Furkan",
            "surname": "Topaloğlu",
            "email": "furkantopalogluu@gmail.com",
            "password": "fuki123",
            "role_id": 2,
            "classes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "IELTS Group 1",
                    "homeworks": null,
                    "materials": null,
                    "users": null,
                    "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Speaking Club Grup 4",
                    "homeworks": null,
                    "materials": null,
                    "users": null,
                    "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2022-09-20T02:54:07.185756+03:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-09-20T02:54:07.185756+03:00"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: The other attributes are default initalized with null resp. time.Date(0,0,...)

Comment: What do you mean by that? I don't want to see them in response.

Comment: Everything should be working as expected, the field you want to omit when empty must be tagged as such. Just add to those fields `json:",omitempty"`. This should do it.

Comment: I am newbie to gorm. so returning zero value while I'm using Preload with custom columns is the normal work flow of GORM, right? Btw, thanks for answer. @ifnotak

Comment: gorm does not return them. Print this data structure with empty data and you will get the same result. You just need to omit them when empty from being part of the json.